# Deploying AWS lambda from a SAM App with AWS Codepipeline & CodeBuild

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm doing a cross-account pipeline for a  SAM application. The same application uses a lambda function (hello_world) with aws_lambda_powertools  and a simple rest API. This is a sample application deployed with "sam init"

The pipeline works and deploys the resources, but the lambda function is missing the extra modules like requests or  aws_lambda_powertools. When testing i get the error `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'aws_lambda_powertools'",`

In the lambda function, I have

```
from aws_lambda_powertools import Logger
from aws_lambda_powertools import Tracer
from aws_lambda_powertools import Metrics
......
```

and there is a
hello_world\requirements.txt file with

```
requests
aws-lambda-powertools[tracer]
```

The pipeline has a Build stage made with AWS CodeBuild, where I use a buildspec.yaml file.

This is the code in the build:

```
- echo "Starting SAM packaging `date` in `pwd`"
- pip install --upgrade pip
- pip install pipenv --user
- pip install awscli aws-sam-cli
- pip install -r requirements.txt
- aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $ArtifactBucket --output-template-file packaged-template.yml
 #- sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $ArtifactBucket --output-template-file packaged-template.yml --region $AWS_REGION
```

If i use  *aws cloudformation package* .... the pipeline deploys the code but without aws-lambda-powertools modules. I guess this is normal since is not supposed to pack modules.

If i use *- sam package --template-file template....* i get this error `Error: Cannot use both --resolve-s3 and --s3-bucket parameters. Please use only one.` THis is dont understand since i do no use --resolve-s3 in my command

My question will be - How to include the modules from the requirments.txt file in the AWS CodeBuild building process so it deploys lambda with all the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The solution

- since this is a SAM app you have samconfig.toml. Edit it, change resolve_s3 to false and you will  not have the
  Error: Cannot use both --resolve-s3 and --s3-bucket parameters. Please use only one

  - in buildpsec.yaml i use this code

  commands:

  - echo "Starting SAM packaging `date` in `pwd`"
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install pipenv --user
  - pip install awscli aws-sam-cli
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - sam build
    #- aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $ArtifactBucket --output-template-file packaged-template.yml
  - sam package --template-file .aws-sam/build/template.yaml --s3-bucket $ArtifactBucket --output-template-file packaged-template.yml --region $AWS_REGION

I added sam build - to build the lamba dependencies
and use this path .aws-sam/build/template.yaml instead of template.yaml  . This is where we have new build cloudformation template (after sam build).

*** i also added samconfig.toml to git ignore list

The only strange thing is that now I cannot see the lambda function in the console(i know - old habits)  because   "The deployment package of your Lambda function "***" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function". The pack has 12 MB and I don't know if that is normal. Any comment will be appreciated.